# Easy way to plot a vector as an arrow

Tags: plotting, vector

Is there an easy way to use the Mathematica command Plot to draw a vector arrow from one point p1 to a second point p2? Like in the plot below where p1=(0,0) and point p2=(4,6)?  I got it to work using LineListPlot, Arrow and Epilog but it seems like there is an easier way.

[image]

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to use `Plot` when you can use `Arrow`? Note that you do not necessarily need `Epilog`, you can use `Show`: `Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}], Graphics@Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]`

Comment: `Graphics[{Arrow[...]}, Frame -> True]`

Comment: There is n0 real reason that I I chose the use Plot - other than it seemed like the obvious path to follow.  Thanks for the great suggestions.  I think I'm heading in the right direction now.

Comment: Also, please take a look at [PlotVector](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotVector/)  and [PlotVector3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotVector3D/) in the Wolfram Function Repository.

Answer (score 5):

```
Graphics[
 {Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {4, 6}}]},
 Axes -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> 6]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ListLinePLot`, e.g.

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, {4, 6}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> Table[{-8, 8}, 2]] /. 
 Line[x__] :> {Blue, Thick, Arrow[x]}
```

[image]